# I have a git workflow file for CI, what I want is to have jobs run if a git diff is found for js and css using git diff only

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions

Here is my workflow file. For now i haven't added the if condition to skip the step if js/css change is not found using git diff as I don't know how to do that.

```
name: Workflow
on:
  push:
    branches: [master]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          repository: ${{ github.repository }}
          token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      - name: Synchronize the repository
        run: |
          git checkout master
          git diff
          git merge origin/master

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          npm ci

      - name: Build assets
        run: |
          npm run prod
```

I am expecting the workflow file to check the git diff. If js/css files found in git diff then run npm run prod or npm run dev command. This should be done after Synchronize repository step

Comment: Can't you use `paths: ['**.css', '**.js']` on the `push` object for that?

Comment: I did that, but doing that would mean that it will only run the workflow when only css/js are made. I have some some migrations file as well which i will add later and if i add a new migration file then i will need another step for it to execute that migration. If possible I would to use `paths: []` in the `name` object

Comment: Adding `paths` wouldn't mean "trigger only for PRs where 100% of the modified files match `paths`", but "trigger for any PR where at least one modified file matches"

Comment: @BenjaminW. you mean that if I add the `paths` on `push` object and specify the files, the workflow will run whether i change a php file or js file. And if js file is found it will run the npm command and if not it will skip that particular step?

Comment: No, if the workflow is triggered, all steps run, unless you guard some with `if`. Can you add some details to the question about your scenario? The title says "have *jobs* run if...", but it looks like you want to skip specific *steps* depending on what files were changed, right?

Comment: @BenjaminW. yes i want to skip specific steps depending on what files were changed

Comment: I changed my workflow code to have this - 
     ` - name: Build assets`
        `if:`
          `paths: ['**js', '**.css']`
        `run: |`
          `npm run prod` but I got the error - `The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/workflow.yml (Line: 27, Col: 11): A mapping was not expected`